# How to end a handler and change activity with a button?

Tags: java, android

Hello I am a college student with a background of html and JavaScript making this app as a side project for work. I would like help with ending a count down timer early via a button press while also taking the user to another activity. I have used two different guides to assemble my code and I have the timer working. I have a limited knowledge of java so any help would be welcomed, here is my code:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1;

    int flag=0;

    // page should show up for 2 seconds then take you to the main page, but I want a button there to stop the count down and take the user to a different page That I will use as a credits page

    private static int TIME_OUT = 2000; //Time to launch the another activity

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class); //Main2Activity is the Welcome page and MainActivity is the home page
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }

        }, TIME_OUT);
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.credit);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                flag = 1;
                Handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, credit.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare a global Handler and use it everywhere. Don't use final in Handler

```
Handler handler;
private static int TIME_OUT = 2000; //Time to launch the another activity

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class); //Main2Activity is the Welcome page and MainActivity is the home page
        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }

}, TIME_OUT);
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.credit);
button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        flag = 1;
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, credit.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sendMessage+removeMessage to CANCEL a post but you cant execute it immediately.

```
Handler h = new Handler() {
public void handleMessage(int what){
    Intent i = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, MainActivity.class); 
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
}
h.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(111, TIME_OUT);
//On your button Listener
h.removeMessages(111);
```

This way the message will be canceled and not fired in the timeout.

Comment: check update, i removed code from your implementation, hope you get it.